# Host Inspector Failed

Tags: amazon-ec2, ubuntu-12.04, cloudera, cloudera-cdh, cloudera-manager

I am trying to install CDH5 on EC2 instances (Ubuntu). Every time I hit the page where host inspector starts to execute, it fails on the worker nodes saying IOException thrown while collecting data from host: Connection timed out. Further digging into the logs, I find another error which says: mismatched DNS Names.

I did edit the /etc/hosts file to include the information of all the nodes in the following manner:

IP FQDN HOSTNAME

Not sure what is going on. Would be really grateful if anyone can help me out with the same.